# Jenkins pipeline always skips stage with 'when' condition for Git tag

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative multibranch Jenkins pipeline I'd like to run a stage only if a Git tag is present. For testing reasons I've set up a simple dummy pipeline. However, the `demo` stage is always skipped. I checked that a Git tag is present and that I pushed the tag as well but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        APP_NAME = 'myapp'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Demo') {
            when { buildingTag() }
            steps {
                echo "Found a tag..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output from Jenkins build**

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Demo)
Stage "Demo" skipped due to when conditional
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

**Log output from cloning the repo**

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to git@gitlab.myhost.com:my-project/myapp.git
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.myhost.com:my-project/myapp.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 1 remote branch
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 1bcf713882dbdba6b8007e0f6c23b44207cbab1e
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on vm-abn-jenk-002 in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build-myapp-app/master
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential 7253b0d3-b5a6-4569-a3ad-5392cba89d9b
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Checking out Revision 1bcf713882dbdba6b8007e0f6c23b44207cbab1e (master)
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.myhost.com:my-project/myapp.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.myhost.com:my-project/myapp.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@gitlab.myhost.com:my-project/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1bcf713882dbdba6b8007e0f6c23b44207cbab1e
 > git rev-list --no-walk 1bcf713882dbdba6b8007e0f6c23b44207cbab1e # timeout=10
```

[image: Jenkins job configuration]

Comment: Possible bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55987

Comment: Can you show the part of the log that clones the repository? _buildingTag_ is only effective when you actually build a tag (e.g. clone and checkout refs/tags/sth), not just a commit that happens to have a tag.

Comment: @raspy I added the log and a screenshot of the job configuration to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the following:

> Checking out Revision 1bcf713882dbdba6b8007e0f6c23b44207cbab1e (master)

This shows that the code is checking out a branch, not a tag. You need to check out a tag to make it work. The output would then be something like:

> Checking out Revision a8deb8ef28d4b83e5f146afe132ac21dee47f225 (TEST_TAG)

Technically the *tag* and *buildingTag* conditions [check](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/blob/7502d14aa4db891302abf48a2c7de7c9ced97f95/pipeline-model-definition/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/when/impl/TagConditionalScript.groovy#L39) whether there is a TAG_NAME environment variable set (*tag* also checks the value). This is set automatically when Git plugin checks out a tag, but is not available when checking out a branch, even if there are tags on the same commit.

Since it seems you are using a Multibranch pipeline, you need to start your build from Tags tab to make it work.